# Where to find URLs for sources.list for debian for running apt-get update?

Tags: debian, apt

Can anyone tell me where to find URLs to put in `/etc/apt/sources.list` for debian so that I could run `apt-get update`?

I couldn't find the precise answer by searching Google.

When I currently try running `apt-get update` I get:

```
W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Failed to open file.  ' [IP: 130.89.148.12 21]

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Failed to open file.  ' [IP: 130.89.148.12 21]
```

I have no idea how to solve this.

Here is how my current `sources.list` looks like:

```
deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
deb-src ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian lenny/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian lenny/updates main contrib non-free
```

I'm running `debian_version` 5.0.8:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version 
5.0.8
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lenny is end of life; its repos have been removed from the normal mirrors.  They now live on the archive mirror.

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like mirror you're being sent to is broken. Try using the [primary mirror](http://www.debian.org/mirror/list) for the country which the machine is hosted in. Also try using HTTP instead of FTP.

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian lenny/updates main contrib non-free
```

If that still doesn't work, pick one of the secondary mirrors.